# MediaTimelineController throwing COMException on FrameworkElement.OnMeasureOverride?

Tags: c#, windows, xaml, uwp, xamarin.forms

I am using the UWP ProjectionManager and the new MediaTimelineController to sync two MediaPlayerElement controls playing the same video file.  The ProjectionManager is projecting a window with the second MediaPlayerElement.  The problem is, as soon as I call Start() on the first MediaPlayerElement I am getting a COMException with the following Message:

```
System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException: Operation is not allowed when Media Timeline Controller is attached.
```

Operation not allowed when Media Timeline Controller is set.
  at Windows.UI.Xaml.FrameworkElement.MeasureOverride(Size availableSize)

It should also be mentioned that the first MediaPlayerElement is a Xamarin.Forms Page, with a Renderer to render the MediaPlayerElement on UWP devices.

Does anything come to mind?  I can't see how the MeasureOverride should be affected by the MediaTimelineController?

Comment: Have you set `MediaPlayer.CommandManager.IsEnable = false`? The CommandManager is usually used to route play/pause/seek commands to the MediaPlayer. The CommandManager object must be disabled when attaching a MediaTimelineController.

Comment: @NicoZhu-MSFT

The problem was fixed with this line: 'DefaultMediaPlayer.SetMediaPlayer(new MediaPlayer());'